# ng-disable is not updating upon the change of variable used in the expression

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to enable/disable a button on the basis of an expression, as in the code below.

But the button is not enabling again whenever the value of `curPage` variable changed.

How to handle this case in angularjs?

```
<button
    id="prevPage" 
    ng-click="prevPageBtnClicked($event)" 
    ng-disabled="{{curPage == 1}}">
        Previous
</button>


<button
    id="nextPage" 
    ng-click="nextPageBtnClicked($event)" 
    ng-disabled="{{curPage == totalPage}}">
        Next
</button>
```

Update 1: controller code

```
var myController = app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.logs = {};
    $scope.curPageLogs = {};
    $scope.itemPerPage = 15;
    $scope.curPage = 1;

    ...

    $scope.nextPageBtnClicked = function(event) {
        if ($scope.curPage < $scope.totalPage) {
            $scope.curPage += 1;
        }
        $scope.generateCurPageLogs();
    }



    $scope.prevPageBtnClicked = function(event) {
        if ($scope.curPage > 1) {
            $scope.curPage -= 1;
        }
        $scope.generateCurPageLogs();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `{{ }}`. Conditional code in ng-if, ng-disabled etc does not require curly braces. Its recommended to use `===`.

```
<button
    id="prevPage" 
    ng-click="prevPageBtnClicked($event)" 
    ng-disabled="curPage === 1">
        Previous
</button>


<button
    id="nextPage" 
    ng-click="nextPageBtnClicked($event)" 
    ng-disabled="curPage === totalPage">
        Next
</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

1. You should use angular expressions i.e., `{{..}}` inside html directives

eg.

```
<input value="{{sampleObj.attribute}}"/>
```

2. You should NOT use angular expressions i.e., `{{..}}` inside angular directives.

eg.

```
<input ng-value="sampleObj.attribute"/>
```

in your code, change your

```
ng-disabled="{{curPage == totalPage}}">
```

to

```
ng-disabled="curPage == totalPage">
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: Exactly the opposite, adding the brackets, solved my problem.